# Change data type and update values in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I had a field in my mongo collection called "preferredCarrier" which stored a string ID I changed it to an object:

> preferredCarrier: { "Id": "string", "Name": "string"}

How do update all old records  to be:

> preferredCarrier: { "Id": "OldId", Name: "" }

[image]

Comment: What version of mongo you are using?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet 4.0

Comment: What is `oldId`? and `name`?

Comment: oldId would be the value "test" Name is a new field , a property of preferred carrier